# How to make nav menu fall onto the page?

Tags: html, css

I was wondering how i could drop my menu from outside the top of the page, to the top of the page. Let me show what I mean. So at the moment I have it like this

<--top of the page-->
<--menu directly at the top-->

So, what i want to do is something like this:

<--just outside the top of the page starts the nav menu-->
<--top of the page-->
<--falls down to where it is currently-->

So i just want it to fall down from outside the top and fall into the page. I assume it's a css animation, but I'm not sure how to do it. Please suggest a method to do so.

Here is my css stylesheet.

```
body {
    font: 12px sans-serif;
    background-color: #eee;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
/* Everything for the navigation */
.nav
{
margin:0 auto;
position:relative;
background:rgba(0,0,0.5);
background-color:#555;
height:60px;
width:50%;
box-shadow:0 0 2px #000;
font-size:13px;
}
.nav ul li
{
list-style-type:none;
display:inline;
margin-top:22px;
margin-left:75px;
float:left;
}
.nav ul li a
{
text-decoration:none;
color:#999;
transition:all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.nav ul li a:hover
{
color:#fff;
cursor:pointer;
transition:all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.logo
{
float:left;
margin-top:15px;
margin-left:75px;
}`
```

and here is my html code if it's needed.

```
<html>
<head>
        <title>Zegita</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body>
        <!--Navigation bar-->
        <div class="nav">
        <!--Logo-->
        <div class="logo">
        <a href="./"><img src="img/thumb.jpg" height="30" width="35" style="border-radius:3px;"></img></a>
        </div>
        <!--End Logo-->
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">My Github</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact info</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!--ending the navigation bar-->

        <!--starting the content area-->

        <!--ending the content area-->
        <!--starting the footer area-->

        <!--ending the footer-->
</body>
</html>`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this very easily by setting the header above the document with a negative margin and using jQuery and `.animate()`

**HTML**

```
<div class="header"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
html,body{
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}

.header{
   background: black;
   width: 100%;
   height: 40px;
   margin: -100% 0 0;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(".header").animate({"margin": 0}, 1000);
```

[**EXAMPLE 1**](http://jsfiddle.net/x982s2v2/)

## **OR**

if you want to use CSS animations you can do:

```
.header{
   background: black;
   width: 100%;
   height: 40px;
   -webkit-animation: animateHeader 1s ease forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes animateHeader {
   from { margin: -100% 0 0; }
   to { margin: 0; }
}

@-moz-keyframes animateHeader {
   from { margin: -100% 0 0; }
   to { margin: 0; }
}

@keyframes animateHeader {
  from { margin: -100% 0 0; }
  to { margin: 0; }
}
```

[**EXAMPLE 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/x982s2v2/2/)

Comment: thank you for your examples, and code :) I'll give it a go, and get back to you if something didn't work. for the meantime, i upvoted it :3

Comment: Works perfectly how i wanted to, but i ran into 1 problem. I've centered my nav using the margin:0 auto; but with the css example which is the one i used, it doesn't put my nav back in the center as it did before. How would i go about fixing it?

Comment: Nevermind, i fixed it right after i typed the comment :p Thank you very much kind sir.